# Docker + Windows Container: Best practice to work with PowerShell

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, containers

Recently I've been investing some time to dive from Docker on Linux with bash (usually using "eux" options) into Windows container with Powershell to gain the same experience in Windows.

However, I have a lot of trouble getting there. Let's begin with the troubling Dockerfile (which will likely be the base for most Windows containers using PowerShell):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2-amd64

SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-NoProfile"]

# Set ExecutionPolicy = Bypass permanently
RUN Invoke-Command -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock { `
    Get-ExecutionPolicy -List ; `
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass ; `
    Get-ExecutionPolicy -List `
    }

# Install chocolatey
RUN Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

# Enable global confirmation and install general build tools
RUN Invoke-Command -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock { `
    $ErrorActionPreference='Stop' ; `
    choco feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation ; `
    choco install --no-progress --no-color -y cmake --installargs 'ADD_CMAKE_TO_PATH=System' ; `
    choco install --no-progress --no-color -y mingw ; `
    choco install --no-progress --no-color -y make `
    }
```

What I personally miss the most is the possibility to chain multiple commands, so I can avoid the creation of superfluous image layers and container restarts.
However, if one of the commands fails, the command won't stop even that I told `Invoke-Command` to stop on errors and within the script block I set the `ErrorActionPreference` variable.

Hope the main problem here is not mainly linked to the missing knowledge in PowerShell, but how PowerShell works in Windows containers.

Thanks!

Comment: `choco` is an executable and I believe it will not `throw a PowerShell error`, instead it will set the variable `$LASTEXITCODE` to a value that's not `0`. It's your responsibility to check that. Probably that's whats happening, I'm not sure, I did not play with `choco` but with all other executables that I did play with, I had to check the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable